# String not having same value in Android

Tags: java, string

I have two variables but same value, one is a String that is retrieved from a database, and the other is generated in the program. For exemple :

```
 String encodedImage="FFD8FFFE002460000D11000000000000000000000000000000F0004001230032"
+"120B510451040000FFDB008400090607080705090807080A09090A0D160E0D0C";
```

//this is the variable generated in the program

```
String vartable="FFD8FFFE002460000D11000000000000000000000000000000F0004001230032\r\n120B510451040000FFDB008400090607080705090807080A09090A0D160E0D0C
```

// this is the string retrieved from database, it is a json then parsed to a string

The string is a representation of a picture so it is much longer but here is the first two lines.
The problem is that if I compare the 2 string

```
if( encodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase(vartable)
```

I obtain that the 2 string does not match 
Any help ?
I am doing a android application and I must have the same string to have the same picture

Answer (score 1):

You have a `\r\n` sequence in one of the strings(`vartable`). Therefor the two strings are not equal - one of them has two characters more. You could have detected this easily by debugging - the length of the two strings is not the same and this is probably one of the first checks that `equals` and its variations perform.

Comment: I guess this is not consider as a character when compiling, this is to return to a new line

Comment: Of course it is considered a character. Please try and debug your program and take a look at the lengths of the two strings that you try to compare. Two strings of different length will never be equal. Maybe you need to remove white spaces before comparing?

Comment: when I put the string in a textview I dont see the \r\n

Comment: Yes, You will not see the \r\n in text view.
Remove them before comparing.

Comment: \n\r appears in the json format but when I pasrse the json to a string I dont see the \n\r

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
vartable = vartable.replaceAll("\r\n", "");
```

and then compare the 2 strings,

```
if (encodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase(vartable))
```

Comment: \n\r appears in the json format but when I pasrse the json to a string I dont see the \n\r

Comment: Can you share your json, or the url?